# How to get the amount of all terms excluding one term in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I have a field with names and want to count all names together excluding one name.

I am using aggregation to get the count of all articles with a given name (here Xman):

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "_all": "*"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "lawyerNameXmanCount": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "lawyerName",
        "include": "Xman"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would simply need the above query negated but thats not that easy for now.

My goal is to get all other names summed up together.

I try different stuff like filter-aggregations with no- and must filters but did not reach my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text from [elasticsearch guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values).

> It is possible to filter the values for which buckets will be created.
>   This can be done using the include and exclude parameters which are
>   based on regular expressions.

And here is the json,

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "tags" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "tags",
                "include" : ".*sport.*",
                "exclude" : "water_.*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, if you want to count all except one then You can use not filter and cardianility aggregation (which gives you estimate sum) but this is only direct way (add individual count) to get actual sum.

Hope this helps!! , Thanks,

Comment: Thx, but i did that already, this gives me the other names, but not summed up:-(
E.g. 10 docs for name "Bman" and 8 docs for "Aman" but not summed up 18 docs for all excluding "Xman".

Comment: You can use not filter and cardianility aggregation (which gives you estimate sum) but this is only way (add individual count) to get actual sum.

Comment: Thx for the Information! If you post this as answer, that for now this is not possible (cardinalitiy aggregation only work approximate) i set it as reasonabel answer.